# Python: Add a column to numpy 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 arrays.

```
a = np.zeros(2)
b = np.ones(2)
```

I want to combine them so that its output is:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

If I had `a = np.zeros((2,1))` and `b = np.zeros((2,1))`, this can done with `np.hstack((a,b))` or `np.append(a,b,1)`. But I don't.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The solution is staring you in the face.  Add the required dimensions. Or be lazy and use a function that adds them for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.c_`

```
>>> a = np.zeros(2); b = np.ones(2)
>>> np.c_[a, b]
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> np.array((a, b), order='F').T
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

Here `order='F'` makes sure that the final result is `C-contiguous`

Answer (score 2):

You can always add a trailing dimension...

```
>>> np.hstack([a[:,None], b[:,None]])
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way or other you need to add the extra dimension to the arrays.

```
In [2]: a = np.zeros(2)
   ...: b = np.ones(2)
   ...:
```

`stack` lets you choose the new dimension:

```
In [3]: np.stack((a,b),axis=1)
Out[3]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]])

In [4]: np.stack((a,b),axis=0)
Out[4]: 
array([[0., 0.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

`np.array` also does it, like `stack` with axis 0 - transpose to get the columns:

```
In [5]: np.array((a,b)).T
Out[5]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

`column_stack` is an older `stack` that add the right dimensions for this case as well.

```
In [6]: np.column_stack((a,b))
Out[6]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

It's a good a idea to learn to do this with `concatenate` and your own addition of dimensions.  And look at the code for the various `stack` functions to see how they do the same task.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reshape them:

```
>>> a, b = np.zeros(2), np.ones(2)
>>> np.hstack([a.reshape(2,1), b.reshape(2,1)])
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```